# Is it possible to have 2 repos on GitHub forked from the same repo and show it so on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to do it?

The reason is, there is a starter template for React / Redux https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter , and there are 2 or 3 sample apps that can be built from it.

So naturally you would fork it and `git clone` to your hard drive and then go on with the project. After you are done with project 1, then for project 2, fork it again and repeat.

But GitHub doesn't allow forking it twice per account.

So what I did was `git clone` that repo, and then did

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:myusername/ReactReduxAppOne.git
git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter
```

but my GitHub repo still will not show that it is forked from the original repo (on the GitHub webpage). Is there a way to make it so?

Comment: Why fork it twice?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but can't that be accomplished with branches?

Comment: @NullDev It sounds like the OP is creating multiple projects based on a project template. Very likely the two projects will be completely unrelated, so branches are not a very good solution.

Comment: right, completely unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to fork a template? Forks are intended to be used when you want to make changes that are then submitted back to the original as a Pull Request.

On the other hand, a template project is intended to be used as a starting point for your own unique projects. Instead of forking on GitHub, you should just clone the template to your local machine. Then create a brand new GitHub repo and add it as a remote to your cloned project. Now you can push your project to GitHub and get on with development.

Comment: if only for the reason to show the project actually came from that template repo... I suppose I could do it in the `README.md`, but if my first project shows that it was forked from there, it'd strange that the second project can't show that

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Yes, a README or other documentation is more appropriate for acknowledging the source of the template.